# How do you reference the root key using JSON Path?

Tags: json, pentaho, jsonpath

I have data like so:

```
{"key": {"name":"hi", "size":10}}
```

"key" is a dynamic value. It isn't fixed. I can access `name` and `size` using this JSON Path:

```
*.name
*.size
```

How can I get the value of "key" itself with JSON Path? `*` gives me the entire row of data, and both `$` and `@` give me "no element found" in my parser.

I'm trying to do this in Pentaho with a JSON Input step.

Answer (score 4):

`$.*` will give you all elements of parent object, in your example you will get something like

```
[
   {
      "name":"hi",
      "size":10
   }
]
```

according to: http://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to do with the Pentaho JSON Input step, as this uses JSONPath as you say. You need to do it another way. For example with the `Modified Java Script Value`:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as one way of interpreting your question:  If you actually want to get the output `["key"]` from your example without having to specify `"key"` in your input. then don't use `jsonPath(data,`*...somequery...*`)` at all.  Simply use `Object.keys(data)`.  I am working in Javascript, and am not familiar with Pentaho, so i don't know if my answer applies to your situation.